# Cannot connect to server using my public key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-16.04, public-key

I copied my public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. Now I'm trying to establish an ssh connection, but it doesn't work.

This is the output from `ssh -v` (server domain and ip address redacted)

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <Server> [ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <server>:<port> as 'jenkins'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:oDdpyTTKXVwLAF7RvyrBmTdtiYusX9Kh5unb/IVhQT0
debug1: Host <server> is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

Already made sure to assign the correct permissions to the content of .ssh on the server and I have another uxder being able to login to the server using public key.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Are you connecting as the correct user (jenkins)? Did you edit the `authorized_keys` in the correct user's home directory?

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-copy-id` takes the guesswork out of migrating keys to your machines. To copy your default key you just run:

`ssh-copy-id user@newserver.com`

If you have multiple SSH keys that you use you can use the `-i` flag to indicate which one you want to send to the new machine. Like so:

`ssh-copy-id -i /path/to/new_id_rsa user@newserver.com`